# Groovy Grails - store object for subsequent requests

Tags: grails, groovy, request

I have a web application and front-end makes ajax request to server in order to get data. In controller I have following logic:

```
def data = []

def method() {
  def objects = []
  ...
  from params determine if it is a first request
  ...
  if (firstRequest) {
    objects = someService.getObjectFromDB()
    data = objects
  } else {
    actions with data object
  }
```

But the problem is that for the 2+ requests `data` is an empty list despite the fact that during the first request I populate it with needed information. How can I use `data` object is 2+ requests?

Comment: You should be careful with this approach, because your objects will be detached from the hibernate session, if your object graph has been partially loaded (ie some relations are lazily fetched) then you will get LazyInitializationExceptions when trying to access objects from the session scope. The Hibernate session is closed after the GSP page has been built (on the first request).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the data object in the user sessions like:

```
session.data = objects
```

And when you enter the method check of the data is already there..

```
if (!session?.data) {
    // first request
    objects = someService.getObjectFromDB()
    session.data = objects
} else {
    // retrieve data from session
    def oldData = session.data
    // do something
}
```

This is probably not the best solution because you will store a lot of information in the session so try to restrict that to a minimal.

Comment: That solution is not thread safe, and you can get session.data updated twice. E.g. if the first request will be retreiving data from db while the second will find that session.data == null. In this particular case you should syncronize on session object.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to move the above logic from the controller to the service class. Benefits of doing this:-

1.Service is by default singleton. You can set the scope to `request` as a result of which you would get an handle to the global data per request.

2.Session will not be overloaded with data.

3.Best part:- You can pass in `params` &/| `request` (defaults of a Controller) to service layer in method calls.