# Grails: How to store/load multiple session variables?

Tags: session, grails

I have a Grails (2.3.6) app and would like to store user-specific session data. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668809/892029), I can use the `session.data` object somehow.

The problem is, that answer seems to indicate that you can only store 1 session variable at a time:

```
session.data = someObject
```

But what if I want my app to have a `fizz`, `buzz` and `foo` variable for each signed-in user? For example:

```
User 1
======
fizz = true
buzz = abc
foo = 3

User 2
======
fizz = false
buzz = def
foo = 193

...etc. for all Users
```

How could I store `fizz` for User 1 inside `session.data`? What about other values?

How could I load (access) the current user's `fizz` (or other) value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `session` is specific to the user (and not only that, but the user's current browser session), so if you are in a controller, you can just treat `session` as a map.  It will inject the session for the user so you can use that.  There is nothing special about `session.data`, that is just the name of the key that developer wanted to use.

If you're asking about simplifying the code, you can use `.with`, but it's not necessary:

```
session.with {
    fizz = true
    buzz = abc
    foo = 3
}
```

which translates too:

```
session.fizz = true
session.buzz = abc
session.foo = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

`data` is just a variable name. You can store your other variables in the same way

```
session.fizz = true
session.buzz = abc
...
```