# Keeping object states in RAM without persisting the data

Tags: grails

I am building a little web game using Grails and I feel like I am missing an important concept.

A game involves an `n*n` grid. Each player plays its turn by clicking a cell.

---

The code needs three Groovy classes: `Game`, `Grid` and `Cell`.

I *could* make this game the usual way, by creating domain classes which persist all the games, grids and cells data. However I am thinking that the **grid data is quite volatile** and that it's not really useful to save the state of the grid just for a few seconds.

My question is, what if I don't want the grids and cells to be persisted but still access their objects? Is it possible with Grails?

---

In other words, I am used to create either:

- web apps where the dynamic data being displayed to the user is always stored into a database,
- desktop apps where the dynamic data can just wait in the RAM as objects which are not being persisted into a database.

How to create a web app which the data can just wait in the server RAM without being saved into a database, and be accessed whenever the user needs it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy Grails - store object for subsequent requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668388/groovy-grails-store-object-for-subsequent-requests)

Comment: Sounds like you need some server side caching. If it's a web app and you have more than one server , you need to look at (distributed caching  frameworks ). ncache , memcached, redis etc) Or build more of a stateful ui on your web app. e.i. javascript frameworks, that hold state and communicate changes to the server. then maybe use some web socket technology such as signalr to communicate changes across the distributed users.

Comment: If that involves more than one server (or it is likely to involve more than one server) then I'd be thinking about some sort a data grid, like hazelcast. It allows you to save almost any type of data, distribute/access around a cluster, supports transactions and more. And nothing gets stored into a database.

Comment: Alright thank you, so a framework like Grails would not have such a purpose? I thought it would since it's running a JVM. Does it just act as PHP for instance?

Comment: Agreed defectus , i was trying to think of the name , but I have heard great things about hazelcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can persist your objects using the grails session:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.4/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html

In general, most web frameworks use a session to store per user data. The default one for grails uses memory. Out of the box you can replace that with cookie or database based storage.

If you need to share state among users, then you can store data on the servletContext, which is available in all your controllers. This gives you a place to store global variables. A bunch of hash tables should give you what you need.

State won't be saved between server restarts, but if you need that then you can use a database or otherwise serialize your objects.

If you want easy persistence, consider using something like enhcache, http://Enhcache.org which allows you to persist a cache to disk pretty easily.

Comment: Even though this is good to know and could be useful because it uses memory, the information of the games I generate (grids) can't be linked to user sessions for several reasons: the grids are generated before the users join the game, also a game/grid is played by two players so I don't want to save the grids twice, and finally the games/grids should be visible to spectators.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't expect the states to be saved between server restarts. Thanks!